# How to clone a VM disk using vim25 Java API?

Tags: vmware

I want to clone a disk in one vm to another vm using Vmware Vcenter API(vim25). Currently I am only able to find examples of cloning VMs and not individual disks. I need to clone individual disks.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by taking a look at the CopyVirtualDisk_Task method that's in the VirtualDiskManager: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-6-5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc%2Fvim.VirtualDiskManager.html